# Python Frequency Table with Percentages

Tags: python, frequency, percentage, frequency-table

How would I create a frequency table in Python that looks like the image attached?

I want to be able to add a title and include a grand total summary at the bottom. Is there a code for this?

[Frequency table with count of instances and percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnE7c.png)

Comment: You can use a `Pandas` data frame for this purpose. I can help more if you can share some of the data.

Comment: This question is far to open and general. Try to be more specific, and also post what you have been trying in Python. Questions like: I want this, show me the code, are hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which could help you. I used the Pandas and NumPy module.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Response':['Yes', 'No'],
    'Number':[5289, 39922],
    'Percentage': ['11.7%', '88.3%']}


df1=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Response','Number', 'Percentage'])

print(df1)
```

Hope this helps! :)